# "Is it possible to schedule local push notifications and retrieve the date from Firestore automatically using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification

I want to create an remind assessment deadline application where the user can add the assessment title, assessment description, attachments, and **assessment deadline**.
For example, let's say the assessment deadline is May 20th, 2023. Starting from May 18th, the user should receive daily reminders with the assessment title and a message reminding them of the upcoming deadline. **Specifically, the user can have multiple assessments. So, if this user has another assessment deadline on May 21st, then reminders should be sent starting from May 19th for that assessment as well.**

This is the scenario that I want, but I don't have any idea how to implement it using Flutter. I have already saved the relevant assessment data in the Firestore database. Specifically, the user can have multiple assessments.

**If you have any ideas on how to implement push notifications, could you please assist me? I am not sure how to start the coding part and would appreciate any guidance you can provide**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily need push notifications for this. You can use local notifications. You can schedule local notifications with the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) library.

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule()
```

You specify the DateTime you want the user to be reminded on. For your use case, you have to schedule a notification for each day you want the notification to be shown.

```
final lastReminder = DateTime(2023, 5, 20, 15, 30); //assessment deadline DateTime;
final penultimateReminder = lastReminder.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
final firstReminder = penultimateReminder.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
```

Note that you have to manually set the notification id to be the id of that assessment reminder. You can prefix the notificationId with 1, 2 and 3, with each number representing each of the notification reminder day. This is needed so that you can cancel the already scheduled reminder for the remaining days when the assessment is marked done.

Comment: If the user clears the application cache, would the reminders still not come? Is Firebase Cloud Messaging the best solution for a scenario like this?

Comment: @DasunDola Firebase Cloud Messaging does not support Push notifications scheduling. Unless you maintain cron job that runs every minute on the backend then it checks for assessments that require a reminder and dispatches push notification. That means, if the user does not have an active internet, they won't get the reminder.